# How likely a setting change made a significant change from test results?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance

Data from single machine at different times (before/after setting change). I ran 5 tests, change a setting, and ran five more tests. I got these results:

A:
2209
1948
2189
2227
2225
A Average: 2160
A Standard Deviation: 119

B:
2763
3055
3117
3083
2876
B Average: 2979
B Standard Deviation: 152

How do I quantify the feeling that the setting definitely made a difference and estimate the probability of the latter five test results just being randomly high?

Comment: That depends, is this paired data or not?

Comment: Data from single machine at different times (before/after setting change).  Each test does not change state of machine in way expected to influence subsequent test.  Unpaired?

Comment: (+1) On your question, similarly, if I have answered it below, you should accept the answer as helpful (the check mark), and/or vote for it with the gray triangle.

Comment: Ask yourself this: what is the chance that the results are just two independent random samples of the same process?  If they were, the chance that all values in one sample would be the five highest of all ten results is $2/\binom{10}{5}=2/252\approx 0.8\%.$ That's low enough to suggest (in many circumstances) that you should proceed as if the change did affect the machine. These kinds of calculations are easy to make in your head and provide quick reality checks of such results.

Comment: @Carl upvoted your answer, but interfaces says my upvote will delay to show since my account is new.  Will accept answer once I'm sure I fully understand it.

Comment: @whuber Helpful, but, I need something to calculate probabilities for small numbers and Mann-Whitney test. Surprised to learn that Mathematica is not using correct algorithm.

Comment: @whuber why doesn't magnitude matter?  For example, what if B average was 2979**0** with a standard deviation of 152?  In the calculation you gave, the difference in result values would be much larger, but the probability the setting made a difference would not have changed.

Comment: @statpad Correct, also, Mann-Whitney test has same problem due to finite number of probabilities for small $n$, e.g., for sign test, does $---$ differ from $+++$? Not significantly it doesn't. $t$-testing would not have that problem but would be noisy and equally misleading.

Comment: Of course magnitude matters.  But to use it, you have to make (much) stronger assumptions about the data generation process than the simple (yet theoretically valid) calculation I presented.  If a simple test that makes minimal assumptions suggests there is a difference, then it's almost always the case that a test which *does* use magnitudes and makes more assumptions will also suggest a difference.

Comment: @whuber understood; magnitude may not matter: The question didn't identify units or meaning of results. To Carl's point, negative results were not ruled out, so proximity of zero doesn't mean anything. The units could be seconds, or nanoseconds, or something else, so a difference of 1, 1000, or 10000 only means there is a difference. The question asked and you and Carl addressed was if there is a _statistical_ difference_, not an _meaningful operational_ difference.  The setting very likely changed the machine results - nothing further is stated or implied by question or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mathematica

A = {2209, 1948, 2189, 2227, 2225};

B = {2763, 3055, 3117, 3083, 2876};

MannWhitneyTest[{A, B}]$\,\rightarrow p=0.00661535$

I know you didn't ask for it, but, the next logical question is whether A and B have the same or different variability. And that is not significant:

ConoverTest[{A, B}]$\,\rightarrow p=0.275588$

In English, the data is unpaired, and group-A probably not normally distributed forcing us to use the nonparametric versions of the available tests. That is, t-testing for detectable difference of means and Levene testing of detectable difference of variance cannot be used such that we apply Mann Whitney testing and Conover squared ranks for different data location (similar to mean values difference detection) and variability of data (similar to difference of variance  detection), respectively. The results imply that we have detected a difference of mean values (actually data locations) as the probability of the same location is small $p=0.00661535$ and that the difference of variability (variances) is not significantly detected.

Whuber suggests that twice (For a two-tailed result) divided by the number the combinations of 10 things taken 5 at a time $\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{10!}{5! 5!}} =\dfrac{1}{126}=p\approx0.00793651$, which is close to the Mathematica Mann-Whitney test result of $p=0.00661535$ is a useful cross check of probability. This is binomial reasoning similar to how the Mann-Whitney U test statistic is constructed.

Note: Normality testing is routine in Mathematica. The possible test results for B are
$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{} & \text{Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
 \text{Anderson-Darling} & 0.445425 & 0.273928 \\
 \text{Baringhaus-Henze} & 0.068726 & 0.571232 \\
 \text{Kolmogorov-Smirnov} & 0.311927 & 0.192981 \\
 \text{Kuiper} & 0.286553 & 0.293762 \\
 \text{Mardia Combined} & 1.3737 & 0.617787 \\
 \text{Mardia Kurtosis} & -0.62975 & 0.528858 \\
 \text{Mardia Skewness} & 0.249052 & 0.617743 \\
 \text{Pearson }\chi ^2 & 2.2 & 0.138011 \\
 \text{Shapiro-Wilk} & 0.875816 & 0.290322 \\
 \text{Watson }U^2 & 0.0754135 & 0.249276 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Of which the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of normality was the most appropriate with $p=0.192981$. The A-group tested out as Kolmogorov-Smirnov normality test $p=0.0213813$.  The interpretation of this is that for group-A normality was rejected and for group-B it was not. This can be seen on this list plot with group-A in blue and group-B in orange.

[image]

Whereas it is quite clear that the group-B results are higher than the group-A results, we just do not have enough information to have good confidence for normality. That is why I did the Mann-Whitney test, and not a t-test.

Comment: "B is not normally distributed" because we assume tests in state A represent the normal distribution and tests in state B represent an abnormal distribution because of the setting change?

Comment: No, rather because that is what is in the data, and, if you want to formulate a hypothesis, you have to test it. In this data, there is no increase of variability detected in group B, so there is nothing to hang one's hat on without more testing.

Comment: One major feature of the Mann-Whitney test is that it does *not* assume Normally distributed data.  It is based on ranks only.  Applying distributional tests to the data is pointless. *Mathematica* approximates the p-value by assuming a Normal distribution *of the test statistic.*  That's a good assumption except for small datasets, for which exact computations are readily available.  In this case the correct p-value is $0.79\ldots\%$.  The Conover test does not assess a shift in location and therefore is not germane to the question.

Comment: @Carl I think you have identified two questions: (1) Is there a significant overall change in **performance** between setting A and setting B?  (2) Is there a significant change in **variability** of performance between setting A and setting B?  Both questions are interesting, but to stay focused, let's say this question regards (1) only.  I think I follow that you are saying "B is not normally distributed" because that is a hypothesis you are _making_ and then testing, not because there is any difference in 'normalness of distribution _inherent_ in the recorded results for B (or A)?

Comment: @statpad Actually on reconsideration it is group-A that tests as non-normal. But testing aside, we just do not have enough data to assume normality with any confidence. Thus, my attempt at using Mann-Whitney, which Whuber tell me I am doing wrong because of small numbers.

Comment: @Carl OK, for people who read comments in future, answer originally stated _B_ was not normal, but you corrected it to A.  A is not normal because it does not pass any of several statistical tests for normal distribution, which in visual terms you depicted as B results forming a "smooth bell" while  A results look like a line with one result out of line.  We can't use equations making assumptions about the distribution (parametric) of values since A is not normal, so we must use parametric tests like Mann-Whitney, but Mann-Whitney does not work well for small data sets.

Comment: @whuber to clarify:  There are 252 combinations of a subset of five values _regardless of order within the five values_ in a set of 10 values (multichoose).  Any of these combinations means there is another set of 5 values in a second subset.   We divide 2 by this because it is a "two-tailed result", meaning that I did _not_ ask what the probability is that the setting change _improved_ the results.  I did ask what the probability is that the setting significantly _changed_ the results (up or down) and there are only two subsets where this could happen (all A < all B, or all A > all B).

Comment: @statpad The plot is just a list plot so the order of points and "bell curve" appearance impart no information (unpaired data). I think the data suggests that $p< 0.008$ for $E(A)=E(B)$, to say more, more data is needed.

Comment: statpad, you seem a little confused about two-tailed tests.  The $2/252$ figure correctly assesses the size of a critical region comprising *two* outcomes: one is where group A exhibits the five highest results and the other is where group B exhibits the five highest results.

Comment: @whuber understood my use of "two-tailed" terminology may be inaccurate; I think we are agreed that since I didn't ask if B improved the results, but just if B has significantly different results than A, that's satisfied by both scenarios you described, thus 2/252 and not 1/252. If we swapped the values of A and B and the question was otherwise identical, it would still be probable the setting made a difference because it would fall into the other critical region identified.