# How many subsets have n values greater/lesser than values in remaining subset?

Tags: combinatorics, subset

For example, given set of ten numbers:

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

Split into two equal-sized subsets. Multichoose calculates 252 configurations of subsets with 5 values (pick 5 from 10).

Only two of these 252 configurations have all five values in the chosen subset are greater or lesser than the remaining subset (order within subsets does not matter):

{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

How to determine how many of the 252 configurations can have *four* values in the chosen subset greater or lesser than all values in the remaining subset?  Examples:

{*4*, 6, 7, 8, 9}
{0, 1, 2, 3, *5*}

{0, 1, 2, 3, *5*}
{*4*, 6, 7, 8, 9}

*Three* values greater or lesser (general rule for set of ten)?
Sets of *eight* or *twelve* numbers (general rule for all sets)?

Comment: Such considerations typically underlie non-parametric tests, and that would seem to be the motivation for posting this question here rather than on the Math site.  However, more information can be obtained by considering rank-based statistics rather than just counting up the inequalities.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics, for example.

Comment: @whuber indeed is follow up question to [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329188/how-likely-a-setting-change-made-a-significant-change-from-test-results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329188/how-likely-a-setting-change-made-a-significant-change-from-test-results) to understand the underlying quick assessment algorithm better and extend to cases where some results overlap.